# Finding upper bound for square of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Following problem: I want to control $(\sum_{r=1}^\infty S(r))^2$ from above.

- I know that the expression is finite,
- and that $S(r)^2 = \mathcal{O}(r^2 \xi^r)$ where $\xi \ll 1$.

So my idea is to use something along the lines
$$
\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty S(r)\right)^2 \leq 2S(1)^2 + 2 \left(\sum_{r=2}^\infty S(r)\right)^2
$$
which leads me to
$$
\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty S(r)\right)^2 \leq \sum^{\infty}_{r=1} 2^r S(r)^2.
$$
My question is whether this step

1. is legitimate
2. is there an easy way to improve this?

Comment: What kind of upper bound are you looking for? You could try using Cauchy-Schwarz on something along the lines of $$S(r) = \left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\left(rS(r)\right)$$ giving you $$\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty S(r)\right)^2 \leq \sum^{\infty}_{r=1} \frac{1}{r^2} \sum^{\infty}_{r=1} r^2 S(r)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\sum^{\infty}_{r=1} r^2 S(r)^2.$$